# Adhoc installation fails (doesn't#t even start...)

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I created an IPA archive and a plist and put both files on a web server. Then I try to open this link in Safari:

```
itms-services://?actions=download-manifest&url=https://www.mydomain.de/mydir/HelloWorld.plist
```

And nothing happens. Console only logs "Client itunesstored is background application", but that's logged often and for me it does not seem to have any impact. Device is included in the provisioning profile.

My impression is, that "itms-services" does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.de%2Fmydir%2FHelloWorld.plist"
```

Comment: Old but gold. Thank you!